# Can Saints Row: The Third cheats be saved across gameplays?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

*Saints Row: The Third* has [dozens of cheats](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=124893314) that can be typed at the cheat screen. However, after I typed some codes and quit the game, when I came back those cheats were gone and I had to retype them to re-unlock them.

**After I type a cheat code, can I make the game remember it?** I wish that when I quit the game and came back, the cheat would already be listed in the cheat screen, so I wouldn't need to re-type it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the game saves, it remembers cheat codes that you entered. However, autosaving is disabled if cheats are activated, so if you activate cheats, you must manually save from then on.

Answer (score 0):

> ...after I typed some codes and quit the game, when I came back those cheats were gone and I had to retype them to re-unlock them

By default, using a cheat in the game will flag your save as a cheat save. This does the ff:

- **disables auto-saves**
- puts a little cheat text on your save from the menu
- disables all achievements
- disables all challenges
- warns anyone you co-op with that it will infect their save if they co-op with you and you have a flagged save loaded

The cheats you entered are saved, so you could easily use/toggle them again anytime without entering the code again. So what probably happened here is that you forgot to do a manual save after entering cheats, and your cheats didn't get saved as auto-saves are disabled.

If you're playing on the PC, you can install the [Rare Vehicle Cheats (includes Additional Cheats)](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/rare-vehicle-cheats-includes-additional-cheats-v5.475/) mod's open version (part of the [Gentlemen of Steelport](http://idolninja.com/sr2.php) mod compilation), which removes flagging caused by cheats, which will allow auto-saves even if you use cheats.